# Splitting a csv into multiple csvs

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am trying to split a csv into multiple files based on a few conditions. For instance, I have a csv as follows:

```
ID    Timestamp  Product  Price
XX      T1         P1       10  
XX      T2         P1       11
XX      T2         P1       12
XX      T3         P1       13
XX      T3         P1       14
YY      T1         P1       20
YY      T1         P2       25
```

Expected output:

File 1: XX_P1_file1.csv

```
ID    Timestamp  Product  Price
XX      T1         P1.      10  
XX      T2         P1.      11
XX      T3         P1       13
```

File 2: XX_P1_file2.csv

```
ID    Timestamp  Product  Price
XX      T2         P1       12
XX      T3         P1       14
```

File 3: YY_P1_file1.csv

```
ID    Timestamp  Product  Price
YY      T1         P1       20
```

File 4: YY_P2_file1.csv

```
ID    Timestamp  Product  Price
YY      T1         P2       25
```

Currently, the code only looks for key(ID,Product), I want to create a condition around "Timestamp" to get the desired results and I am finding it tricky to add that.
Code:

```
    filein = open(filepath)
    csvin = csv.DictReader(filein)
    csv_files = {}
    files = []
    headers = ['ID','timestamp','product', 'price']

    for row in csvin:
            key = (row['ID'], row['product'])
            if key not in csv_files:
                # create the csv file
                fileout = open('{}_{}.csv'.format(*key), 'w')
                dw = csv.DictWriter(fileout, headers, extrasaction='ignore')
                dw.writeheader()
                csv_files[key] = dw
                files.append(fileout)  # to close them later

            # write the line into to corresponding csv writer
            csv_files[key].writerow(row)
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Jithu, have you looked into using [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/getting_started/10min.html)? If I were you, I would load the csv file into a pandas DataFrame using pandas.read_csv(), filter the data into separate DataFrames using boolean masks and then save the results using DataFrame.to_csv().

Comment: what are the conditions of separating the timestamps?  It looks like you want the first instances of T1/T2/T3 for a particular ID/Product to go to file1, and second instances to go to file2.  Can there be more instances?  Are your data files pre-sorted as shown?

Comment: I would definitely recommend pandas for this problem. In addition to being able to get a much more pythonic solution, given the vectorized methods, it should be much more efficient to do in pandas.

Comment: Jithu did any of the solutions work for you? Can you accept the best one as the solution by pressing the checkmark next to the answer?

Comment: Thanks guys for your help. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a modification to your code that works.  It tracks instances of ID/Product keys to direct the timestamp to the correct file.  It assumes your file is already sorted by the sortkey (a requirement for `itertools.groupby`) but you can pre-read and sort all the lines in with `csvin=sorted(list(csv.DictReader(filein)),key=sortkey)` instead if needed.

```
import csv
import itertools
import operator

headers = ['ID', 'Timestamp', 'Product', 'Price']
sortkey = operator.itemgetter('ID', 'Product', 'Timestamp')
files = {}

with open('input.csv', newline='') as filein:
    csvin = csv.DictReader(filein)
    for (id_, product, timestamp), group in itertools.groupby(csvin, key=sortkey):
        for instance, row in enumerate(group, 1):
            key = id_, product, instance
            if key not in files:
                filename = f'{id_}_{product}_file{instance}.csv'
                print(f'Starting {filename}')
                fileout = open(filename, 'w', newline='')
                writer = csv.DictWriter(fileout, headers)
                writer.writeheader()
                files[key] = fileout, writer
            files[key][1].writerow(row)

print(f'Closing {len(files)} output files')
for openfile, _ in files.values():
    openfile.close()
```

Output:

```
Starting XX_P1_file1.csv
Starting XX_P1_file2.csv
Starting YY_P1_file1.csv
Starting YY_P2_file1.csv
Closing 4 output files
```

Files match your desired output given your input.

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick with creating a “File” column with `.cumcount`. This column will be used later to help create the file names dynamically and then dropped before sent to multiple dynamically named . csv files in a loop with `.groupby` on the two columns necessary to group the the datasets and accompanying filenames into dynamic files. You don’t need to specify any logic for the “Product” column since the “Timestamp” resets to 1, so it would be flagged as having to go into a new file.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('your_filename.csv')
df['File'] = df.groupby(['ID', 'Timestamp']).cumcount()+1
for (i,f), x in df.groupby(['ID', 'File']):
    x.drop('File', axis=1).to_csv(f'{i}_T{f}_file{f}.csv', index=False)
df
```

output:

```
   ID Timestamp Product  Price  File
0  XX        T1      P1     10     1
1  XX        T2      P1     11     1
3  XX        T3      P1     13     1

   ID Timestamp Product  Price  File
2  XX        T2      P1     12     2
4  XX        T3      P1     14     2

   ID Timestamp Product  Price  File
5  YY        T1      P1     20     1

   ID Timestamp Product  Price  File
6  YY        T1      P2     25     2
```